# How do I define the output when trying to run Python in Code by Zapier?

Tags: python, postman, integration, zapier

Zapier is erroring because I haven't defined an output. Here is the example they provide on their FAQ

```
return {'name': input_data['name']}
```

In the Python I copied from Postman the JSON payload doesn't look the same so I don't have the same place to define the output. Here is my code

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://stackoverflowpost.com"

payload = json.dumps({
  "LeadInfo": "Lead Info",
  "CustomerFID": None,
  "RegCommunityFID": "None",
  "NameLast": "input_data['lastName']",
  "NameMiddle": "None",
  "NameFirst": "input_data['firstName']",
  "Title": "Mr",
  "NameLast2": "TEST",
  "NameMiddle2": "Zap",
  "NameFirst2": "Zap",
  "Title2": "",
  "Suffix2": "",
  "StreetAddress": "Zap St",
  "City": "Townsville",
  "ZipCode": "12345",
  "StateCode": "DE",
  "PhoneHome": "input_data['phone']",
  "EmailHome": "input_data['email']",
  "Rating": "Rating",
  "LeadSource": "LeadSource",
  "RegistrationNotes": "string",
  "ExternalID": "EXID",
  "Status": "Status",
  "ProspectNumber": "2",
  "WCCustBuyerInfo": {
    "ContractName": "ThisContract",
    "WCBuyers": [
      {}
    ]
  }
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Where can I define the output so that it only outputs the JSON body without triggering a different error in my code?

Anytime I added 'return' to the code I get a new error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a variable called output with an array in it.

eg:

```
output = [{"xyz":"abc","123":456}]
```